# On the solution to the equation $\dfrac{1}{2} f'' = f^3 - f$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find some textbooks which present on the derivation of the equation $\dfrac{1}{2} f''= f^3 - f$ with boundary conditions $f(0) = f(\infty) = 0$ and its solution ($f(x) = \tanh x$).

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: complicated  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2+f%22+%3D+f%5E3+-+f

Comment: @Isham : no it's not so complicated if you choose other constants. You see much of the complicatedness in those expressions is in bad choice of constants.

Comment: @mathreadler you are surely right...I don't know I just muliplied the equation by $f'$ to integrate..

Comment: @Isham : Maybe it was not your fault. Softwares are not perfect. I think multiplying with stuff to make chain rule work can be a sensible thing to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $f'$ we have

$$
\frac 14((f')^2)'-\frac 14 (f^4)' + \frac 12(f^2)'=0
$$

or integrating

$$
(f')^2=f^4-2f^2+C_0 = (f^2-1)^2+C_1
$$

with solution

$$
f(x) = \frac 12C_2^{-1} e^{\pm x}\left(1-C_1 +C_2^2e^{\mp 2x}\right)
$$

etc.